# SQL string concatenation with if statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have simple query for full text search, data comes from HTML form inputs. If statement checks or it was filled all three inputs with array_key_exists and then concatenate all strings, but if someone didn't fill first or second input and then my query WHERE part is `WHERE AND contract = $var` so in this situation AND is not needed. What is solution for my problem, how i can solve this? When AND is needed just add to query string and when didn't needed don't add.

```
    $sql = "SELECT 
                slug, 
                title, 
                company, 
                location, 
                email, 
                street, 
                city, 
                phone, 
                url, 
                description, 
                image, 
                created_at 
                FROM jobs
                WHERE ";

    array_key_exists('paieska', $segment) ? $sql .= "MATCH(title, description) AGAINST('".urldecode($segment['paieska'])."') " : '';
    array_key_exists('darbo-laikas', $segment) ? $sql .= "AND contract = '".$segment['darbo-laikas']."' " : '';
    array_key_exists('miestas', $segment) ? $sql .= "AND location = '".$segment['miestas']."'" : '';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just add a `1` to the original where statement (And `AND` before your first `$sql` if statement). This will always be true, and will return all the records.

If `darbo-laikas` exists, your query would be `...FROM jobs WHERE 1 AND contract...` which would work correctly.

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            slug, 
            title, 
            company, 
            location, 
            email, 
            street, 
            city, 
            phone, 
            url, 
            description, 
            image, 
            created_at 
            FROM jobs
            WHERE 1 ";

array_key_exists('paieska', $segment) ? $sql .= "AND MATCH(title, description) AGAINST('".urldecode($segment['paieska'])."') " : '';
array_key_exists('darbo-laikas', $segment) ? $sql .= "AND contract = '".$segment['darbo-laikas']."' " : '';
array_key_exists('miestas', $segment) ? $sql .= "AND location = '".$segment['miestas']."'" : '';
```

Comment: It works only if first part with MATCH didn't filled in other way i got SQL syntax error

Comment: Did you make sure to add `AND ` before the first `MATCH(title, description)` @SkySonny?

Comment: Oh.. my bad, i didin't read so carefully, everything works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @SkySonny Be sure to accept the answer that works the best for you, or clarify if you still need help. (The green checkmark to the left of a post)

Answer (score 0):

try this, add **'AND'** in every last statement

```
array_key_exists('paieska', $segment) ? $sql .= "MATCH(title, description) AGAINST('".urldecode($segment['paieska'])."') AND " : '';
array_key_exists('darbo-laikas', $segment) ? $sql .= "contract = '".$segment['darbo-laikas']."' AND " : '';
array_key_exists('miestas', $segment) ? $sql .= "location = '".$segment['miestas']."' AND " : '';
```

before execute, delete last char('AND') using

```
rtrim($sql, "AND ")
```

**note:** rtrim should with whitespace, because your **'AND '** using whitespace too

Comment: It works just had to remove both AND from last if statement. Thanks!